# Нужно реализовать галерею на сайте! подскажите в с помощью чего это сделать ? (пример приложен в фото пунктиром)

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно реализовать галерею на сайте! (пример приложен в фото пунктиром)

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/BxMMBa  с минимальным кодом css и js

Answer (score 1):

Если на чистом css надо, то можно вот так сделать:

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.gallery {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
label {
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
[for="firstFoto"] {
  background-image: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/750997/48bfcda0-637d-408b-95a5-4123f3e003f5/s1200');
}
[for="secondFoto"] {
  background-image: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1779763/2b7df1e8-bbd3-4a82-be9e-6dea46ef9fff/s1200');
}
[for="thirdFoto"] {
  background-image: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/985144/cea5cd64-23bd-4d72-aef6-b3ff252c4275/s1200');
}
[for="fourthFoto"] {
  background-image: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/38069/203472834-sokol-250-1461077903.61/s1200');
}
.result {
  width: 74%;
  height: 495px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
#firstFoto:checked ~ .result {
  background-image: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/750997/48bfcda0-637d-408b-95a5-4123f3e003f5/s1200');
}
#secondFoto:checked ~ .result {
  background-image: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1779763/2b7df1e8-bbd3-4a82-be9e-6dea46ef9fff/s1200');
}
#thirdFoto:checked ~ .result {
  background-image: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/985144/cea5cd64-23bd-4d72-aef6-b3ff252c4275/s1200');
}
#fourthFoto:checked ~ .result {
  background-image: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/38069/203472834-sokol-250-1461077903.61/s1200');
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <input type="radio" name="gallery" id="firstFoto" checked />
  <input type="radio" name="gallery" id="secondFoto" />
  <input type="radio" name="gallery" id="thirdFoto" />
  <input type="radio" name="gallery" id="fourthFoto" />
  
  <div class="result"></div>
  
  <label for="firstFoto"></label>
  <label for="secondFoto"></label>
  <label for="thirdFoto"></label>
  <label for="fourthFoto"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

это можно сделать при помощи css и javascript или даже при помощи только css. можно покопать в сторону jquery, если не охота программировать.

если дадите больше вводных, например, какой движок сайта, можно будет дать более подробный ответ

Comment: В данный момент интересно реализовать это при помощи css.

Comment: "Охота" крепкая! Простите, не удержался.

Answer (score 0):

Скорей всего, чисто на css, это будут дикие костыли. Реализовать это можно при помощи javascript. Я писал это не думая о дизайне и прочем стафе, потому что вопрос заключался в том, как сделать такую галерею. Здесь в этом коде по клику на определенную картинку, скрипт получает ее `src` и вставляет в блок справа. Добавляйте сколько угодно фото. Все будет работать. Вот. Изначально, скрипт берет путь первой картинки и вставляет в блок справа.

```js
let all_imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper img'),
 right_column_img = document.querySelector('.right-column img');
 
right_column_img.src = all_imgs[0].src;
  
 all_imgs.forEach(function(e){
  let src = e.getAttribute('src');
  e.addEventListener('click', function(){
   right_column_img.src = src;
  })
 })
```

```css
* {
 padding: 0; margin: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
 display: flex;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 800px;
 height: 700px;
}

.left-column {
 width: 200px;
}
.left-column img {
    display: block; /* чтобы убрать отступы у картики ибо img это инлайн */
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
}
.right-column {
 width: 600px;
 height: 100%;
 background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-column">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554545416-f8bfd9f59149?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=80">
 <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554545286-68f95b3405ad?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60">
 <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554545286-0014de69f57b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60">
 <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554545286-e18ec21129b4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60">
 <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554226321-24fdcddd5a55?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60">
 <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554215352-d03d9deba830?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60">
 <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554024104-9a372355b0b8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    <img src="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Например: